# why isn't nREPL server logging info level messages?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, nrepl

From Clojure project directory, `M-x cider-jack-in` starts the nREPL server and the Cider REPL. in the latter:

- `(clojure.tools.logging/info "hello")` does not output anything in the server buffer,
- but `(clojure.tools.logging/warn "hello")` does.

am i missing a configuration? very new to Clojure development...

Comment: `logging/info` from a Clojure file does output properly though...

Comment: Do you have a log4j.properties file on your classpath? What is its contents? Do you have anything else setting log4j settings?